# Find remaining vertices of a square, given 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I need a hint for this problem.

Let the vertices of a square ABCD represent on the Argand diagram the complex numbers a,b,c, and d respectively. A,B,C,D are taken anti-clockwise in the order named.

If $$a = 3 + i, b = 4 - 2i$$, find c and d.

For a different problem, where square was at the origin, I used the idea that $$i(z_1)$$ is an anti-clockwise rotation and since it's a square etc. But here it's not at the orgin. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a translation so that one of the vertices goes to the origin, then make the inverse translation.

Comment: Got it, I did a translation of (3+i) and (4-2i) to get 2 points and then moved them back after rotation to get, C = (7-i) and D = 6 + 2i, which checks out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $b$ to $c$ is a rotation through $\pi/2$ of $a$ to $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can find the side of the square from $|b-a|$.  If you think of walking around the square anti-clockwise, at each corner you make a left turn of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and go the same distance.

Comment: Haven't studied polar form of complex numbers yet, this and @Ben Bosisel idea seems more elegant one I have studied that! Until then that translation solution worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need polar form, all you need to know is that when you multiply a complex number by $i$ you rotate it by 90 degrees, counterclockwise.

Answer (score 0):

A rotation in the complex plane around point $b$ with angle $\theta$ has the expression $z \mapsto b+(z-b)\cdot e^{i\theta}$, where $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$.

Comment: Thanks, need to study the trignometry form of complex numbers first!